# Django - pagination based on search criteria

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-pagination

I am having issues getting results when clicking on page 2 and above - most likely due to url issues. I have a list of names and if I search on e.g. "John" I want them to be separated by pages if number of names > e.g. 10.

My Views are as follows: (searching works fine)

```
def name_search(request):
    if 'q' in request.GET:
        q=request.GET.get('q', '')
        pvt_list = pvt_data.objects.filter(full_name__icontains=q)

        #Pagination
        p = Paginator(pvt_list, 10) # Show 10 contacts per page.
        page_num = request.GET.get('page', 1)

        try:
            page = p.page(page_num)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            page = p.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            page = p.page(1)

        context = {'items' : page}

        return render(request, 'home/name_search.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'home/name_search.html')
```

My urls.py file is

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('name_search', views.name_search, name='name_search'),
    ...
]
```

My html file is

```
{% for pvt in items %}
        {{ pvt.full_name }}
{% endfor %}

<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if items.has_previous %}
            <a href="?page={{ items.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}

        <span class="current">
            Page {{ items.number }} of {{ items.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>

        {% if items.has_next %}
            <a href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

When I search, I get the following link 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/name_search?q=John' with the first 10 names correct.

When I click on next button I get the following link:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/name_search?page=2

Changing the link manually to
http://127.0.0.1:8000/name_search?q=John/page=2
does not work...

Any response is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a solution might be to add your search parameter to your href.
so instead of:

```
<a href="?page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

try:

```
<a href="?q={{ q }}&page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you need to pass the query to the next/previous pages as well.

```
{% for pvt in items %}
        {{ pvt.full_name }}
{% endfor %}
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="step-links">
        {% if items.has_previous %}
            <a href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&page={{ items.previous_page_number }}">previous</a>
        {% endif %}
        <span class="current">
            Page {{ items.number }} of {{ items.paginator.num_pages }}.
        </span>
        {% if items.has_next %}
            <a href="?q={{ request.GET.q }}&page={{ items.next_page_number }}">next</a>
        {% endif %}
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Also worked perfectly - just missing the '</a>' at the end there it seems.